# how to implementation "graph.facebook" in php file

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

i want to use http://graph.facebook.com/XXX in my site
how i do a php file that have use this system and show my facebook details when i enter the link?

XXX = userrname

i want that the site show the details of the facebook user that enter the site

i tried everything but nothing, i dont want to make ap like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

$api_key = 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID';
$api_secret = 'FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET';
$redirect_login_url = 'http://www.yoursite.com/somefolder/file.php';



// https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/

// initialize your app using your key and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($api_key, $api_secret);

// create a helper opject which is needed to create a login URL
// the $redirect_login_url is the page a visitor will come to after login
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $redirect_login_url);


// First check if this is an existing PHP session
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    // create new session from the existing PHP sesson
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
    try {
        // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
        if ( !$session->validate() ) $session = null;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        // catch any exceptions and set the sesson null
        $session = null;
        echo 'No session: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}  elseif ( empty( $session ) ) {
    // the session is empty, we create a new one
    try {
        // the visitor is redirected from the login, let's pickup the session
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
        // Facebook has returned an error
        echo 'Facebook (session) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        // Any other error
        echo 'Other (session) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
    // store the session token into a PHP session
    $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
    // and create a new Facebook session using the cururent token
    // or from the new token we got after login
    $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
    try {
        // with this session I will post a message to my own timeline
        $request = new FacebookRequest(
            $session,
            'POST',
            '/me/feed',
            array(
                'link' => 'www.finalwebsites.com/facebook-api-php-tutorial/',
                'message' => 'A step by step tutorial on how to use Facebook PHP SDK v4.0'
            )
        );
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        // the POST response object
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
        $msgid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');
    } catch ( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
        // show any error for this facebook request
        echo 'Facebook (post) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
    // now we create a second request to get the posted message in return
    if ( isset ( $msgid ) ) {
        // we only need to the sec. part of this ID
        $parts = explode('_', $msgid);
        try {
            $request2 = new FacebookRequest(
                $session,
                'GET',
                '/'.$parts[1]
            );
            $response2 = $request2->execute();
            $graphObject2 = $response2->getGraphObject();
            // the GET response object
            echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject2, 1 ) . '</pre>';
        } catch ( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
            // show any error for this facebook request
            echo 'Facebook (get) request error: '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
} else {
    // we need to create a new session, provide a login link
    echo 'No session, please <a href="'. $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'publish_actions' ) ).'">login</a>.';
}

// use this for testing only
//unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);
```

thanks,
mtj

Comment: After login, you make a simple API call for `/me` to get the current user’s details.

Comment: but i don't want to make an app, i want to make a php page like the site..this is an example of "Mark Zuckerberg":   http://graph.facebook.com/4

Comment: Well, you can’t do it without an app, because with API v2 getting any user details requires an access token.

Comment: And neither can you get _“the details of the facebook user that enter the site”_, because without having the user log in to an app first, you won’t know anything about a Facebook user that is on your site.

Comment: yes but i want to make a page like this graph site, without application than wont access the details

Comment: up... i need to do this pliz help me